# Ember build error . How do I run it on gitlab runner?

Tags: ember.js, frontend, gitlab-ci, ember-cli, gitlab-ci-runner

While running  `./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember build --environment=production`  on my local machine it works fine . But on gitlab runner it is giving me this error :

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
ENV Summary:
  TIME: Tue Aug 18 2020 08:01:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - /usr/local/bin/node
  - build
  - --environment=production
  EXEC_PATH: /usr/local/bin/node
  TMPDIR: /tmp
  SHELL: /bin/bash
  PATH:
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /usr/bin
  - /sbin
  - /bin
  PLATFORM: linux x64
  FREEMEM: 1133453312
  TOTALMEM: 7833886720
  UPTIME: 339452
  LOADAVG: 1.95654296875,1.080078125,2.80615234375
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz - 2900
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz - 2900
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz - 2900
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz - 2900
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.15.0
  - brotli: 1.0.7
  - cldr: 35.1
  - http_parser: 2.9.3
  - icu: 64.2
  - modules: 64
  - napi: 6
  - nghttp2: 1.41.0
  - node: 10.22.0
  - openssl: 1.1.1g
  - tz: 2019c
  - unicode: 12.1
  - uv: 1.34.2
  - v8: 6.8.275.32-node.58
  - zlib: 1.2.11
ERROR Summary:
  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at isMultipartPath (/builds/mosaic-apps/omnivise/aurora/pa-aurora-
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  - errorMessage: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler` plugin. 
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  - errorType: Template Compiler Error
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: siemens-addon-help-desk/templates/components/issue-create.hbs
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler` plugin. 
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler
  - nodeName: broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler
  - originalErrorMessage: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  - stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
=================================================================================
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My ember version :

**"ember-cli": "^2.16.2"**

**"ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0-beta.1"**

**"broccoli-asset-rev": "2.6.0"**

Tried to change the version of ember-cli , doesn't seem to be working . Also , cannot find the solution anywhere online . What could be the problem here?

Comment: Can you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: Are you locking your dependencies down to specific versions using yarn or NPM? Is the `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` committed to your repository? Otherwise a different version on a package may be used locally than on CI.

Comment: The issue has been resolved . The issue was with one of the version of repositories that I was using .